# How to fix parse error installing Open MCT?

Tags: javascript, git

I'm currently trying to install NASA's Open MCT ([Link](https://github.com/nasa/openmct/blob/master/API.md#building-from-source)) and already encounter errors during installation. After running `npm install`, I get the following error message:

```
{ Error: Parse error using esprima for file: C:/Users/MCTUser/openmct/node_modules/painterro/build/painterro.min.js
Error: Line 258: Unexpected token *
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:29563:47
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3063:37
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3011:25
    at Function.prim.nextTick (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:29929:9)
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3010:26)
    at Object.then (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3060:23)
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:29548:36
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3063:37
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3011:25
    at Function.prim.nextTick (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:29929:9)
  fileName:
   'C:/Users/MCTUser/openmct/node_modules/painterro/build/painterro.min.js' }

events.js:174
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Error: Module loading did not complete for: openmct, src/MCT, src/plugins/plugins, platform/features/notebook/bundle, platform/features/notebook/src/actions/AnnotateSnapshot, painterro
    at Function.build.checkForErrors (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:31556:19)

    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:30099:19
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3081:39
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3021:25
    at Function.prim.nextTick (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:29929:9)
    at Object.errback (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3020:26)
    at Object.callback (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3006:23)
    at Object.then (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:3060:23)
    at build (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:30056:12)
    at runBuild (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:32006:17)
    at Object.execCb (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\requirejs\bin\r.js:1941:33)
Emitted 'error' event at:
    at DestroyableTransform.onerror (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_readable.js:640:52)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at done (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:202:25)
    at C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:139:7
    at DestroyableTransform._flush (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\gulp-requirejs-optimize\index.js:97:4)
    at DestroyableTransform.prefinish (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_transform.js:138:10)
    at DestroyableTransform.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at prefinish (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:619:14)
    at finishMaybe (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:627:5)
    at endWritable (C:\Users\MCTUser\openmct\node_modules\readable-stream\lib\_stream_writable.js:638:3)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! openmct@0.14.0-SNAPSHOT prepare: `node ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install && node ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the openmct@0.14.0-SNAPSHOT prepare script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\MCTUser\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-08-14T12_42_14_925Z-debug.log
```

I installed GIT and Node.js as requested in the tutorial. Does anyone know what could be the cause and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

1. install npm-check-updates(ncu)
2. use ncu update all modules, see ncu help, update the package.json
3. run "npm install" update modules
4. reinstall gulp ver3.x.x as the gulpfile.js write in old way
5. modify d3-* path "build" to "dist" in file opencmt.js
   then it run npm install , it will ok